# How to display old value inside aura:iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**Requirement:** This may sound crazy but my requirement is to show an input field to change the value and a text field to display the original value.

**Problem:** Once user changes the value in input field, the original value displayed is also rerendered. This might be a feature in Lightning world but how do I solve this for my requirement.

Here is sample code for the problem:

**Example.cmp**:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="ListVar"
                    type="List"
                    default="[{'dt':'2017-01-01'},
                              {'dt':'2017-01-31'}]">
    </aura:attribute>
    <table>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.ListVar}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ui:inputDate value="{!item.dt}"
                                      displayDatePicker = "true">
                        </ui:inputDate>
                    </td>
                    <td>{!item.dt}</td>
                </tr>
        </aura:iteration>

    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Initially it displays as below:

[image]

But if I change the input value, the original value displayed also changes.

[image]

Comment: Have tried using the `#` yet?: [When to use {#v.attrib} vs {!v.attrib}?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138348/when-to-use-v-attrib-vs-v-attrib/138359#138359)

Comment: @martin It is funny. I read that when it was initially posted but never really understood it and did not even bother to understand it completely. Now it is clear. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: @javanoob Just one way binding wont help you here since it will always show a constant value .Have you tried it ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I tried with `#` instead of `!` for showing initial value and it seem to be working. Are you saying, this will cause other problems? Thanks!

Comment: @javanoob When should the original value display update? Never? If that's the case, then `#` should cover you, otherwise you might need two attributes to store the old and new values, which you can update in your controller when you want to.

Comment: @javanoob Exactly what sfdcfox said .If you are storing old value always then you need another attribute

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, the original value should always represent the value stored in the database. For this, I guess using `#` should work right?

Comment: @javanoob yes then one way binding will work .

Comment: @martin Can you add that as an answer so this thread is closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a one-way binding with the `{#v.attrib}` syntax to set the value when the component is rendered initially, and not update when the attribute value is changed:

```
<td>{#item.dt}</td>
```

See also: [When to use {#v.attrib} vs {!v.attrib}?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138348/when-to-use-v-attrib-vs-v-attrib/138359#138359)

Comment: how to get old value of an attribute in controller? I am creating another attribute just to store old value. But that attribute is also reflected with updated value.