# Dynamically changing variant and iconName on lightning:button when clicked?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I restructured my table a bit and my previous actions broke. However, I wish to have the currently clicked lightning button in a table (in an aura:iteration) change from neutral to success once clicked.

Below is the component:

```
<aura:component description="ResourceTiles" implements="forceCommunity:searchInterface" controller="MainBrowser">

<aura:attribute name="resources" type="Resource__c[]" access="public" />

<aura:attribute name="selectedResourceId" type="Id" access="public" />


<aura:attribute name="currentColor" type="String" default="neutral" />
<aura:attribute name="currentImage" type="String" default="utility:add" />


<aura:registerEvent name="ResourceSelected" type="c:ResourceSelected" />



<div class="slds-scrollable--x">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Car Selection"></div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Model">Car Model</div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Engine Information">Engine</div></th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.resources}" var="resource">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <lightning:button variant="{!v.currentColor}" iconName="{!v.currentImage}" value="{!resource.Id}"
                                      aura:id="allButtons" onclick="{!c.changeColor}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!resource.Name}">
                        {!resource.Name}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!resource.Comment__c}">
                        {!resource.Comment__c}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and below is the controller:

```
 changeColor: function(component, event, helper) { 



    var allButtons = component.find("allButtons"); 
    if ($A.util.isArray(allButtons)) {
        allButtons.forEach(button => {
            button.set("v.currentColor", "neutral")
            button.set("v.currentImage", "utility:add")
        })
    }


    var currentButton = event.getSource(); 
    currentButton.set("v.currentColor", "success");
    currentButton.set("v.currentImage", "utility:check");
},
```

My question is, where is my logic flawed? I want the currently clicked button to change from "neutral" in variant and "utility:add" in iconName to "success" and "utility:check" once clicked.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround solution to it.

markup:

```
<aura:component description="ResourceTiles">
<aura:attribute name="selectedResourceId" type="Id" access="public" />
<aura:registerEvent name="ResourceSelected" type="c:ResourceSelected" />

<aura:attribute name="resources" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
<lightning:datatable aura:id="lightningTable"
                     data="{! v.resources }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="Id"
                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"
/>
```

controller:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.mycolumns', [
        {type: "button", typeAttributes: {
            label: '',
            iconName: 'utility:add',
            name: 'selectRecord',
            title: 'selectRecord',
            disabled: false,
            value: 'edit',
            variant: {fieldName: 'variantValue'},
        }},



handleRowAction: function(component, event, helper) {
    var resource = event.getParam("row")
    var action = event.getParam("action");
    if (action.name == "selectRecord") {
        var event = component.getEvent("ResourceSelected");
         event.setParams({
                resourceId: resource.Id, // 
        });
    }
 event.fire();
 helper.addRow(component, resource);

},
```

and the helper:

```
addRow: function (component, row) {
        var data = component.get('v.resources');
        data = data.map(function(rowData) {
            if (rowData.Id === row.Id) {
                rowData.variantValue = 'Success';

            }
            else {
                rowData.variantValue = "Neutral";
            }
            return rowData;
        });
        component.set("v.resources", data);
 }
```

Comment: Can you also add the component markup to the answer?

Comment: Sure, added the markup.

Comment: Thanks - answer is clearer explicitly showing the`lightning:datatable`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [lightning:button](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_button.htm) documentation these are the attribute names to set:

```
currentButton.set("v.variant", "success");
currentButton.set("v.iconName", "utility:check");
```

Assuming you don't want all the buttons set to the same thing, probably best not to bind all the buttons to one pair of attributes so maybe use:

```
<lightning:button
        variant="{#v.initialColor}"
        iconName="{#v.initalImage}"
        value="{!resource.Id}"
        aura:id="allButtons"
        onclick="{!c.changeColor}"
        />
```

**PS**

Related to the comment about the visibility of the attributes, one approach is to create your own wrapper component (so that it is in your namespace and so access to its attributes are not blocked by the LockerService).

**PPS**

The wrapper would be (with the `changeColor` function moved too):

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="variant" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="iconName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="resourceId" type="Id"/>

    <lightning:button
            variant="{!v.variant}"
            iconName="{!v.iconName}"
            value="{!v.resourceId}"
            onclick="{!c.changeColor}"
            />

</aura:component>
```

referenced in your existing component like this:

```
<td>
    <c:button
            aura:id="allButtons"
            variant="{#v.currentColor}"
            iconName="{#v.currentImage}"
            resourceId="{#v.resourceId}"
            />
</td>
```

Comment: I tried that too without any success, getting error saying:
Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.set(): 'variant' of component 'markup://c:ResourceTiles {958:0}' is not visible to 'markup://c:ResourceTiles {958:0}'.

Comment: @erikvm The dreaded LockerService presumably... If it is that see the PS.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Also, your suggestion with the "variant="{#v.initialColor}" - isn't that exactly what I'm doing right now? I'm not seeing any difference

Comment: @erikvm On the `{#` difference to `{!` see e.g. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138348/when-to-use-v-attrib-vs-v-attrib. The wrapper deal is to just add the same attributes to your component and pass them into the `lightning:button`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the wrapper deal? What specifically should I add as attributes? Because from my original post - isn't that what I have done? 
<aura:attribute name="currentColor" type="String" default="neutral" />
<aura:attribute name="currentImage" type="String" default="utility:add" />
And then in the lightning:button
<lightning:button variant="{!v.currentColor}" iconName="{!v.currentImage}"

Comment: @erikvm I've added more detail in a PPS.

Comment: Thanks Keith, is that little "c" the only thing that could mess things up? :O it sounds quite weird that locker service disallows me from using handlers in the SAME component

Comment: @erikvm The little c is how you reference another of your custom components from a custom component of the same namespace. Not 80% its LockerService here: generally you can't poke around inside a component of a different namespace from JavaScript.

Comment: But all the logic lives in the same component, why would I need the c

Comment: @erikvm The idea is that the c:button component is a _separate component_ to your current component so you can have an instance per row. But looks like you have a solution so lets leave it.

Comment: You know what's funny. I actually tried that before everything - and that worked out fine, however, I had several issues with that approach, which is why I tried to put everything into one component.

I do find it strange that LockerService is bugging out over things like that..

Comment: @erikvm You should try mixing `lightning:tabset` and `lightning:tab` with your own components - things like component.find are blocked too. Think the namespace mechanism becomes too intrusive for truly productive development; something based on containment would make more sense but I guess its too late now...